# classes, constexpr constructors, and std::string

Tags: c++, destructor, allocation, constexpr

I've been messing around with constexpr as replacements for enumerations lately, but I've ran into an issue with strings (ostensibly).

Here is my code:

```
namespace Constant {
    namespace Implementation {
        using std::array;
        using std::string;

        using type = uint8_t;

        namespace Items::Compile_Time {
            template<class element, type size>
            struct Ray {

                const array<element, size> constants {};

                constexpr explicit Ray(const array<element, size> constants_in) : constants(constants_in) {}

                element constexpr operator[](const type index) const {
                    return this->constants[index];
                }
            };

            static constexpr type
                methods = 0,
                signals = 1;

            // Plan on cleaning this up later.
            constexpr auto BooleanIndicator = Ray<Ray<int, 1>, 2>(array<Ray<int, 1>, 2> {Ray<int, 1> {array<int, 1> {0}}, Ray<int, 1> {array<int, 1> {1}}});
        }
    }
    using namespace Implementation::Items;
}
```

This works fine. But, if I replace the 'int' template parameters with 'string' and put strings into their respective places (replacing the most-nested 0 and 1), then I get an error about the instantiation having a nontrivial destructor.

Why is this? I assumed all arrays, including strings, were trivial. Are they allocated on the heap?? I'm guessing if that's the case then it might work with const char* but I haven't tried yet (don't want to unless I have to). If they do go on the heap, is there a way to force them onto the stack?

Future thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::string` is not an array. It allocates its contents on the heap (cons SSO) and as such it can't be made `constexpr` in the current C++ (there are proposals in the works to make `constexpr` "dynamic" allocation possible).

However, there are several workarounds to use compile-time strings in one way or another, like embedding them into template parameters (`Foo<'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'>`). You can also just use `const char *` in most cases,

Comment: I'd suggest `char[]` instead of `char*`, as the former preserves size of the array (so you could use e. g. `std::size` on it).

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer! I misassumed how strings were stored apparently. In response to your mentioned workaround: isn't that informationally equivalent to just typing chars where I need them, since templates are compile-time? I guess it's hard for me to see the benefit, but I'm just a beginning C++ user. I think I'll default to const char* for the time being.

Comment: @joe_chip or `array<char, N>`. But I was looking at the code in the question where the author already stores strings in array. he wouldn't be able to store strings of different sizes in such a structure. Only pointers.

Comment: @AnthonyMonterrosa sometimes you may want to parametrize your type based on a string. For example for some sort of compile-time reflection or maybe compile-time regexp or something. People are creative.

Comment: Oh I see now. Thanks for the explanation

Comment: @AnthonyMonterrosa No problem. here is one cool example https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/metaparse/user_manual.html

Comment: @DanM. didn't notice that (is it supposed to be used in `BooleanIndicator`?). In that case, `std::string_view` would work, it's constexpr-friendly.

Comment: @joe_chip yep, `string_view` would also work, since it's basically a pointer with a size.